# Trouble in understanding a concept of topology.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $\Sigma \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$, where $X$ is any non-empty set. Then if $\Sigma = \{\varnothing\}$ I have understood that this subbasis generates the indiscrete topology. But when $\Sigma = \varnothing$ then does it also generate the indiscrete topology? I have a little bit confusion here. Please help me so that I can overcome such misconception.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topology generated by a family $\Phi$ is the smallest topology $\tau$ such that $\Phi \subset \tau$.

We have that $\emptyset \subset \{\emptyset, X\}$, right? And there is no smaller topology than $\{\emptyset, X\}$. Therefore...

OBS: Your definition of "topology generated by" can also be the set of arbitrary unions of finite intersections of the family. In order for this to generate a topology no matter how "degenerate" the initial set is, then you must consider empty unions and empty intersections, from which also follows that the topology generated by $\emptyset$ is $\{\emptyset, X\}$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the empty subbasis generates the indiscrete topology. The empty intersection is $X$, whereas the empty union is $\emptyset$.